# Почему Binance возвращает "Please log in first"

Tags: java, post, binance

Я хочу отправить POST запрос на Binance и написал такой код:

```java
public class Main {


    private static final String API_KEY = "xxx";
    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "yyy";
    private static final String HMAC_SHA256 = "HmacSHA256";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String baseUrl = "https://www.binance.com";
        String urlPath = "/bapi/futures/v1/private/future/copy-trade/copy-portfolio/create";

        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";
        String contentType = "application/json";

        // -----

        Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("agreeShare", true);
        body.put("leverageMode", "FOLLOW_LEAD");
        body.put("marginMode", "FOLLOW_LEAD");
        body.put("investAmount", 200);
        body.put("costPerOrder", 100);
        body.put("copyModel", "FIXED_AMT");
        body.put("leadPortfolioId", "3885096629774668032");


        final Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder()
                .addHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, userAgent)
                .addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .addHeader("X-MBX-APIKEY", API_KEY)
                .url(baseUrl + urlPath);
        Request request = requestBuilder.post(RequestBody.create(body.toString(),
                        MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8")))
                .build();

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("signature", getSignature(""));

        OkHttpClient client = HttpClientSingleton.getHttpClient();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String responseAsString = getResponseBodyAsString(response.body());

        System.out.println("Response: " + responseAsString);
    }

    private static String getSignature(String parameters) {
        byte[] hmacSha256;
        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(SECRET_KEY.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA256);
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256);
            mac.init(secretKeySpec);
            hmacSha256 = mac.doFinal(parameters.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to calculate hmac-sha256", e);
        }
        return Hex.encodeHexString(hmacSha256);
    }

    private static String getResponseBodyAsString(ResponseBody body) throws IOException {
        if (null != body) {
            return body.string();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Почему в ответе я получаю:

```
Response: {"code":"100001005","message":"Please log in first.","success":false}
```